# How can I get wrinkles out of a dress I can't Iron or wash?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I recently bought a pretty, secondhand prom dress from a thrift shop. Unfortunately, it is covered in little wrinkles!

It is made out of a silky, polyester fabric, and has little dots of glitter. It has some bigger, on purpose folds, and I don't want those flattened out.

The washing instructions are:

- **Spot clean only by a professional dry cleaner**
- **Do not clean entire garment**
- **Do not apply heat to garment**

This is not the same as [How to remove creases from my shirts without ironing?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/how-to-remove-creases-from-my-shirts-without-ironing), as my garment cannot be soaked and then chucked in a tumble dryer. Only parts of the dress can be cleaned as mentioned above and there cannot be any heat applied to it - either through an iron or through a tumble dryer.

Comment: As you've mentioned, it says to only get it cleaned by a professional dry cleaner - they'll also be able to iron it for you as they'll have whatever is necessary to do the job - without heat there isn't a lot that can be done other than soaking the wrinkled areas and hanging it straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steaming wrinkles out works rather well. I would recommend trying to steam it as lightly as possible to ensure you don't damage the dress. Additionally, small hand-held steamers would allow you the opportunity to steam out wrinkles where you want to without affecting the entire dress (to include those intentional folds you mentioned).

Answer (score 4):

Take it with you the next time you take a [hot] shower. Hang it up somewhere, preferably high. As long as it doesn't bother you, don't turn on the fan to let the steam build up. I do this all the time, as I am too lazy to iron things, and it doesn't work well on large wrinkles, just small ones. This should let the on purpose wrinkles stay and the little ones go away.